# Como hacer que en vez de que me salga una respuesta para cada resultado salga todo junto?

Tags: java, java-swing, jpanel

Hola estoy tratando de realizar en java Swing una ventana donde el usuario inserta el numero deseado y muestra por pantalla la tabla de multiplicar de dicho numero, he conseguido que se muestre pero me saca cada respuesta por separado y debo ir pulsando aceptar, como podría hacer que se me mostrara el resultado por ejemplo debajo de la palabra calcular sin sacar ventanas adicionales o si es con joptionpane como sacar toda la tabla de multiplicar junta?

este es mi codigo:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Main {

    private JFrame frmCalculaUnaMultiplicacion;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main window = new Main();
                    window.frmCalculaUnaMultiplicacion.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Main() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmCalculaUnaMultiplicacion = new JFrame();
        frmCalculaUnaMultiplicacion.setTitle("Calcula una tabla de multiplicar");
        frmCalculaUnaMultiplicacion.setBounds(450, 200, 450, 300);
        frmCalculaUnaMultiplicacion.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frmCalculaUnaMultiplicacion.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblIntroduceUnNumero = new JLabel("Introduzca un numero para calcular su tabla de multiplicar");
        lblIntroduceUnNumero.setBounds(54, 27, 338, 14);
        panel.add(lblIntroduceUnNumero);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Calcula");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                multiplicar(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(149, 96, 136, 23);
        panel.add(btnNewButton);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(105, 65, 201, 20);
        panel.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
    }

    public void multiplicar(int num) {
        int total = 0;
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i<=10; i++) {
            total = i*num;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmCalculaUnaMultiplicacion, i+"x"+num+"="+total);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema radica en que cada iteración, invocas al método [showMessageDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)) y esto hace que cada vez muestre una ventana.

La solución es invocar al método cuando el bucle termine su ejecución, sin embargo, en cada iteración, necesitas ir concatenando el resultado y guardarlo en una variable de tipo `String` (en este caso, la llamé `formato`). Y al final, simplemente, pasas el contenido de la variable al segundo parámetro del método `showMessageDialog`.

```java
public void multiplicar(int num)
{
    int total = 0;
    int i = 0;
    String formato = "";
    for (i = 0; i<=10; i++) 
    {
        total = i*num;
        formato += i+"x"+num+"="+total + "\n";
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmCalculaUnaMultiplicacion, format, "Tabla de multiplicar del "+ num, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!! no sabia como hacer que solo me mostrase una ventana

Comment: @azucarilla También puedes optimizar el código usando la clase [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Con esto puedes modificar el contenido del objeto y evitar que en cada iteración se proceda la concatenación + creación de un nuevo objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Para sacar toda la tabla de multiplicar junta podrias guardar cada resultado en un String e ir concatenando cada resultado, y después del for mostrar la lista ejemplo:

```
public void multiplicar(int num) {
        int total = 0;
        int i = 0;
        String lista ="";

        for (i = 0; i<=10; i++) {
            total = i*num;
            lista+= i+"x"+num+"="+total+"\n"; // Concatenas con += y añades un salto de linea con \n

        } 

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmCalculaUnaMultiplicacion, lista);
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!! no sabia lo de concatenar +=

Comment: Si se trata de String sirve para concatenar, pero si se trata de int,double,float,etc lo que hace es sumar el valor actual que tiene la variable con el nuevo valor, de igual forma sirve para restar, multiplicar y creo hasta dividir solo cambiando el + por la operación matemática correspondiente.